# How to full page with angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I still don't know Angular.js, but, i need make a website with angular.js. To gain time, i bought this theme: http://iarouse.com/admin-square/dist-v1.2/index.html#/dashboard

i've created this page: http://sabixao.felipemartinin.com.br/#/pages/entrar

But, i would like this page open full, like this page: http://sabixao.felipemartinin.com.br/#/pages/signup

How can i make this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the reply sabithpoker. Where i define that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was asking what you mean by "open page full"?

Comment: Make this: http://sabixao.felipemartinin.com.br/#/pages/entrar open like this: http://sabixao.felipemartinin.com.br/#/pages/signup - Make a page open without the header and side bar...

Comment: Its not an easily answerable question. For a hint, the other header is hidden in login page using a function `isSpecificPage` in `AppCntlr`, and the header in login page is part of the login template.

Comment: sabithpocker thank you so much! I put the #/pages/entrar in isSpecificPage and works!